# Does Insurgency allow for cross platform play between Mac and PC?

Tags: insurgency

Can I play Insurgency on a Mac with people who are on PC, or is online play segmented into PC and Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated on the [official website](http://www.playinsurgency.com/),

> Playable on both PC and Mac OSX and supports multiplayer cross-compatibility.